# I have sediment in my water and toilet - will replacing my well water filter help?

Tags: plumbing, water, well, water-filtration

See question.  We just moved in and I'm worried the filter hasn't been replaced in a while.  Will replacing the filter help with sediment removal?  Also, any tips on how to look up what filter to buy?  I'm including a photo here (with a water bottle for size reference) if that helps identify the filter size.

Thanks so much!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As an owner of a similar system, I can shed some light on the subject. If you are experiencing sediment in the house, the filter currently in place has destroyed itself if any appreciable time has passed. The build up of particles in the media restrict water flow, increasing the effective pressure on the pleated paper, wound fiber or carbon particles or whatever your filter once was. The pressure has to go somewhere and the filters are not made for excessive pressure.

Additionally, this type of filter is more or less standard. You can toggle off the valves (release the downstream pressure) and unscrew the housing to remove the current filter. If you're getting sediment in the house, the filter isn't doing anything useful and removing it will change nothing, but allow you to confirm the size of the replacement unit.

These filters are rated by ad copy to be good for ninety days, but in extreme conditions, that number may be optimistic.

[One source](https://www.filtersfast.com/Whole-House-Water-Filters-cat.asp) shows the typical assortment of cartridge filter options.

[image: filter choices]

Image courtesy of linked page, not to be considered as an endorsement.

As you can see, there's a general consistency of size across the board. You can have confidence that nearly any filter of this sort will fit your enclosure.